# Woocommerce - Want to block a user agent from accessing specific product pages

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, redirect, cloudflare

I want to block this user agent

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; sweetcouch/1.0; +http://www.sweetcouch.com)

from accessing specific product pages on my site. I have tried using Redirection plugin but it does not work. Please help
[image]

Edit: I am using CloudFlare (I think it interferes with useragent but I get the correct useragent in Wordfence)

Comment: Have you tried that plugin with a full URL?

Comment: Yes, I added full URLs but the plugin converts them automatically.